# How to disable WebStorms unused function color feature?

Tags: javascript, webstorm

I was wondering if anything knows how to disable the feature in WebStorm where if you create a function and don't call it yet, the color will just stay green and not gray.

I went inside the preferences area and changed my global function colors to green but they only turn green if I call them. For any uncalled functions will stay gray.

[image: Example of gray function names]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Go to File -> Settings...
- Open Editor -> Colors & Fonts -> General
- Save the current scheme as a custom one
- expand *Errors and Warnings* on the right
- change the color for *Unused symbol*