# How to make a used variable not turn white in Webstorm

Tags: javascript, webstorm

I was wondering if anyone knows how to disable the feature in WebStorm when a function is called the variable doesn't turn white. I've set the default color to green but when I call that function it turns white.

I've look around in the preference area but I'm kind of stuck now...Thanks

Example of the variable "Account" turning white:
[image: Example of the variable "Account" turning white]

Comment: Could you please clarify a little: do you want the variable color to be green?

Comment: Hi..Yes, as of right now the "Account" variable is white because I have invoked it below but if I do not call it then it will be green. Is there a way to make it just stay green and have it not change whether I call or don't called it?

Comment: So your default variable color is white, but unused variable color is green, and you want them both to be green, correct?

Comment: Yes...thats correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `Settings -> Editor -> Color & Fonts -> General`.

On the right in `Errors and Warnings` find `Unused symbol` and uncheck the `Foreground` (and `Effects` if you don't want the unused variables to be underlined).

Note: if you are using one of the default Color Schemes, you will have to copy it to be able to edit it. Just press a `Save As...` button on the top of the same section.

[image: Settings -> Editor -> Color & Fonts -> General]

**Warning:** this will also affect unused parameters, functions, classes and private member declarations. But after checking [the other question you asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39157199/how-to-disable-webstorms-unused-function-color-feature) it seems like that is what you want.

Comment: @BrianSaminathen This site goes both ways. If you expect help, you should reward those who help you by accepting their answer.  Read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)